# Windows Forms Designer destroys form layout

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

This morning I stumbled over a weird issue in Visual Studio's Windows Forms designer. I have a form which worked for about a month now without changes. It looks like this in the application:

[image: Screenshot of how the form should look like]

(text made unreadable because I'm not entirely sure of the legal implications here).

Now starting today, apparently (I think I had the form open in the designer yesterday without problems) it looks like this in the designer:

[image: Screenshot of how the form looks in the Windows Forms Designer]

Looking at the diff, every control (or nearly every one—labels were not affected, but that may be related to AutoSize) got a width of 311 pixels. Lines like the following are common throughout the file after the designer messed with it:

```
this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(311, 24);
```

Wherever *that* value comes from. Furthermore one label got the interesting text `"潐瑲⼠倠獯瑩潩㩮攀瑵慲ⱬ"` (it doesn't make any more sense in its raw bytes).

When I don't open the form in the designer nothing bad happens, the project even builds when the files are untouched and it looks fine when running the program. But opening the designer triggers aforementioned changes in the designer-generated code and those changes persist when compiling (obviously).

On a co-worker's machine this doesn't happen at all (yet he can't open datasets without crashing VS, so perhaps both setups here are a little weird ...).

I seriously wonder what's going on here. Any ideas?

**ETA:** I can't change size of the controls in the designer once it went on its resizing rampage. Resizing merely causes some visual artifacts as if the control *was* resized but it's still at 311 px width when checking.

**ETA 2:** Weirdly enough: Opening the designer (causes corruption, so far so good), then going into pending changes with AnkhSVN and reverting all changes to the files reverts the corruption too. The form looks like it should even in the designer. Until I close and re-open it again.

Comment: Is there any source control system involved? If so, which one?

Comment: We use Subversion here. But the .Designer.cs file gets only changed as soon as I open the designer. The file itself hasn't changed for about a month in SVN.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but have experienced weird and inexplicable behavior from VS many times myself and just wanted to commisserate. Extremely frustrating! Good luck on this one...

Comment: Thanks, Tom :-). Well, the code editor itself is something I like very much, but the designers lean to instability at times :/

Comment: that text looks a little like arabic to me ;)

Comment: It wouldn't be left-aligened, then :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the culprit. I recently installed [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx). And while I couldn't directly link that behavior to RockScroll I noticed that some forms had the scrollbar replacement of it drawn over them. *And* controls on that form changed size without reason.

Uninstalled RockScroll and it solved the problem. Thanks for all the input, anyway.

Comment: I've just had similar issues with RockScroll affecting how my form objects are redrawn. 

I found the problem would surface when I viewed the forms after debugging. None of the controls on my form were visible anymore.

Not really something I could live with, so I've also uninstalled RockScroll.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to clean your project ? (I'm afraid it won't solve anything, but it's an easy step worth trying)

---

Also, could you clean your Visual Studio cache ? It worked numerous times for me in similar situations.

Here are some links regarding the VS Cache Hell : [1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/VSDesignerCache.aspx) [2](http://zachsaw.blogspot.com/2008/07/application-data-winforms-cookies.html) . Please feel free to edit my post if you find some other useful information regarding this.

Comment: Cleaning the project doesn't help, unfortunately. And where can I find an option to clean the VS cache? I just looked through the options but didn't find anything.

Comment: There's no such option. You need to close VS, and remove the folder manually. I'm updating my post to add some guidelines regarding how to do this.

Comment: Doesn't help here too :-(. I think as a temporary workaround I will just leave that dreaded form alone. If any changes are necessary then my colleague can make them.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new blank form, to copy the designer code into it, to rebuild, and then to delete the old form/rename the new one to the old name? Of course, you would loose the checkin history for this form :(

Comment: I'll try such drastic measures later, I think. At the very moment this form doesn't need any changes and the problem as such is confined to my environment here; others can edit it just fine which is even weirder.

Comment: +1 anyway, since those have been the only sensible suggestions so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do that in one click in the designer using the "make same width" tool.

In my experience, if Visual is freezed during a build, it's pretty common to click at a random location on the screen to test whether VS is done with the current task)

Just an idea, though.

Comment: It happens consistently upon opening the designer. I've been trying stuff for the better part of the last 2½ hours. Furthermore, the number 311 doesn't even appear in the original designer-generated code, so something like "make same with" (even though I didn't click it) would probably have a hard time resizing *every* control to a width that no control had before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have recently installed another language pack (Korean maybe).

Comment: No, I didn't. And I wouldn't expect a language pack to cause random corruption (I doubt those Chinese characters [it's not Hangul] make any sense at all).

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing some manual layout or anchoring in form's constructor or OnPaint methods? I once had a similar problem because I was trying to modify some elements' positions manually, and designer was passing an invalid ClientRectangle (or something) while rendering.

Comment: Just some binding source initialization going on in the Ctor/Form.Load. in total 35 lines of code in the class itself, nothing of that related to the form layout :/