# Winforms Control Alignment Issue - Controls Move Position When Re-Loading Design View of Form in VS2019

Tags: c#, winforms, position, controls, tabcontrol

I'm placing controls on a TabPage of a TabControl which has it's anchor set to Top, Right, Bottom, Left.

I set the Anchor of any Control within that TabPage to Top, Right.

Every time I open the design view of the form, the Controls move roughly the width of the form to the left OR their size is wiped out to 0,0. Each re-load causes the Controls to jump left again as their Location Left becomes an ever increasing negative value.

This problem has only existed since adding a UserControl to another Tab within the Same TabControl.

If I set the anchor of the Control to Top, Left, the problem goes away, except for the fact I can never position the controls where I need them other than programmatically, which is a pain and makes the code quite cryptic.

This bug was mentioned in a previous post and has clearly existed in VS for a decade or so. It has already been asked here: [How to resolve Windows Forms designer issue - controls move on debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12581023/15006773) but the answer didn't 'fix' the underlying problem, it was just a workaround.

I'm using VS2019 and it's a .Net 4.6.1 C# Winforms application.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32142897/14171304).

Comment: Thanks @dr.null It looks like switching to docked panels may be the root I have to go. It's going to be a time consuming job as it's an array of complex controls and still a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness. The issue here turned out to be using Anchored UserControls inside a TabControl. I ended up moving the content of the tab to a Modal Form. Not idea but stopped the problem happening.